# Get Error creating bean with name 'resourceUrlEncodingFilter' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, apache-tiles

I tried to upgrade the project's Java version(8 to 21) and Spring boot version(2.3.4 to 3.2.1 ).

I resolve the dependency and it's built successfully. Apache Tiles were used in this project.

But when I try to run it, I get this error.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceUrlEncodingFilter' defined in class path resource

Comment: You'll need to share with us the complete stacktrace. No way to know the issue with only this message.

Comment: And try to go smaller steps. Update Spring Boot to 2.7.x, Java 11, Java 17, Spring Boot 3.2, Java 21. And test thoroughly after each step.